# Instaling laravel on linux mint

Tags: linux, laravel, linux-mint

I am kinda a new one with laravel and mint. I just cn't get the stuff out - whats is going on. I need some answer like for a monkey actually. So whatever i will accept any question thanks a lot for any help.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework v5.4.9 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.8 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.7 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.6 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.5 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.4 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.3 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.25 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.24 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.23 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.22 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.21 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.20 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.19 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.18 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.17 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.16 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.15 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.14 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.13 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.12 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.11 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.10 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.4.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.4.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.4.0, v5.4.1, v5.4.10, v5.4.11, v5.4.12, v5.4.13, v5.4.14, v5.4.15, v5.4.16, v5.4.17, v5.4.18, v5.4.19, v5.4.2, v5.4.20, v5.4.21, v5.4.22, v5.4.23, v5.4.24, v5.4.25, v5.4.3, v5.4.4, v5.4.5, v5.4.6, v5.4.7, v5.4.8, v5.4.9].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gmp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Comment: "the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system" I think it's pretty obvious you need to install the mbstring PHP extension...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the mbstring extension in PHP. I'm not sure if Mint uses apt or some other package manager, buy try:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring
```

and

```
phpenmod mbstring
```

You may have to play around with those commands to match your PHP version, but that should get you started.

Comment: tnx a lot gotcha :)